# whatsapp not displaying contacts in alphabetical order

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

In my phone i saved some contacts start with "**1**" as below

```
1 Alex
1 Joseph
1 karthik
1 Rajesh
Anderson [ without 1]
```

so in  whatsapp also those contacts are displayed first as above order. now i removed "1" from those names , so **after "Alex"**, it should **display "Anderson"** in whatsapp now, but still whatspp displaying contacts in same above order.

I cleared **cache** from whatsapp, still same result, I dont want to reinstall, any other solutions ?

Comment: Try force quitting WhatsApp From Settings and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: @MarkHettwer i tried, but not worked......

Comment: What user12345 is saying is that whatsapp now shows the contacts without the figure 1, but fails to reorder the names to be in alphabetical order. I and my colleagues have similar problems. When we edit a contact name, it retains it's former position in the contact list. Whatsapp doesn't refresh the list to the point of repositioning the new name to where it should be in the alphabetic order. Please how can we fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try refreshing contacts in WhatsApp. From the main screen click on the new chat tab (green circle on the bottom) then open the menu and select "refresh"

Comment: So you said you removed the "1" and the contacts still have "1" before them? In that case refreshing should definitely help

Comment: Thanks, i tried as you said, but it didt worked for me , also i removed `1` from contacts, it succesfully updated in `contacts` , but not in whatsapp......

Comment: Try force stopping WhatsApp, or reboot the phone

Comment: i tried both , but not worked......

Comment: Must be the same contact is saved twice on the phone. Try this: delete the contact from your phone then refresh WhatsApp, if the contact name is still there, that means it saves somewhere on your phone. If it does get deleted then add it back and the 1 shouldn't be there